# Problem with grid container (Pokedex with HTML, CSS and JS)

Tags: html, css

There is a list of things that i want to do:

> I want the search container to be on the top left corner, the pokemon list below the search bar and the pokemon info on the right side
> The pokemon card are inside the pokedex container

The problem is, when i change something like the card size, the size of the container also change. id like to have a fixed size container

`

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search {
  grid-area: search;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.pokedex {
  grid-area: pokedex;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  height: 100%;
}

.pokemon_info {
  grid-area: pokemon_info;
  background-color: rgb(172, 166, 155);
  height: 97vh;

}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "search search pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info"
    "pokedex pokedex pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info"
    "pokedex pokedex pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info";

  padding: 5px;
  align-content: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  border-color: antiquewhite;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(202, 179, 130, 0.8);
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pokemonList {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pokemonCard {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 110px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

`

`

```
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item pokedex">
            <ol class="pokemonList">
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 1</li>
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 2</li>
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 3</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item pokemon_info">pokemon_info</div>
        <div class="grid-item search">search</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

`

I made some changes in the css but i dont really no how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your worried about the cards overflowing into the right pokemon_info section you can add padding to the `pokemonList` class to make sure the cards won't overflow into that area. If this isn't the issue you were havin you'll have to explain more for me haha sorry!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search {
  grid-area: search;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.pokedex {
  grid-area: pokedex;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  height: 100%;
}

.pokemon_info {
  grid-area: pokemon_info;
  background-color: rgb(172, 166, 155);
  height: 97vh;

}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "search search pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info"
    "pokedex pokedex pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info"
    "pokedex pokedex pokemon_info pokemon_info pokemon_info";

  padding: 5px;
  align-content: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  border-color: antiquewhite;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(202, 179, 130, 0.8);
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pokemonList {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.pokemonCard {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 110px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item pokedex">
            <ol class="pokemonList">
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 1</li>
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 2</li>
                <li class="pokemonCard">poke 3</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item pokemon_info">pokemon_info</div>
        <div class="grid-item search">search</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This solve one of the problems haha How can i increase the pokemon_info container size(horizontaly) and decrease the container search(verticaly) ?